# Switching branches brings committed folders and files of the previous branch

Tags: git, branch, git-commit

I have been working on GIT for 3 years, but don't remember facing this issue.
I have created a new repository, where each branch has a different code. The folder structure is roughly the same at the outer level, but some sub-folders and a few files change for each branch (quite a common situation).

I have an empty branch which I use as base to create new customer branches. I have created 'n' customer branches from here. For the 1st Customer branch, I copied the code from my local to the 1st branch. Commited and pushed the changes. Now when I checkout the second branch (ideally should be empty), but the 1st branch code remains as untracked files. I'm doing a clean -df before copying fresh code to each branch.

Why do I get the **committed** changes from the previous used branch, to my new branch, as untracked files?

Git Version - 1.7

Comment: Git version? This is not the expected behaviour indeed.

Comment: yes.. I kept repeating this for all branches. The behaviour is constant. version - 1.7.11.4

Comment: What is the source of the second branch which you checked out?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "empty branch": a branch either contains commits, or does not exist at all. (Well, there's the half-created "unborn branch" state in which the name is in `HEAD` but the reference does not exist, but you can't check that out.) Do you mean instead a branch whose tip commit has no files?

Comment: So, when I checkout any new branch, I expect it to be empty, so that I can add the code. But it isn't. as I said, git clean -df cleans it. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes Torek, An initial commit with no files.

Comment: You cannot make an initial commit with no files afaik.

Comment: @1615903: you can, it's just generally awkward (`git commit --allow-empty` when the index has no files in it and there is no previous commit, for instance).

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you committed and pushed the first branch, which is `master`, you defined what the starting point is in your repository.  Every branch which comes after this will be relative to this starting point.  So when you ran `git clean -df` you didn't go back to "empty", you simply removed all files from being tracked.  When you then pasted in your second branch files, everything showed up as being untracked.

What I think would make the most logical sense here would be to initialize your new repository with a branch who is a common ancestor to all your customer branches.  After this, you can clobber all files for a given customer, create a branch, and push it out to the new repository.

Comment: My first branch is not master. Master is the initial branch. I created all my customer branches from master. Hence all the branches were initially empty before I added the code,

Comment: Yes, but `master` in which repository, the old one or the new one?  Do you understand that every branch in Git, other than possibly very first commit in `master`, is just a pointer relative to some other branch/commit?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen except orphan branches - for which the behaviour that OP describes DOES happen.

Comment: @1615903 I don't see why he would want to create orphan branches.  Either clone the first repository and go from there, or use a common parent branch as the source for the other branches.  When Git doesn't work the way you expect, it might be because you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: I did not create orphan branches. It was the default master branch which we got whence repository created (In gerrit, through the admins). I'm also noticing this behaviour when i switch between two customer branches. If the previous branch has any extra folders, they don't go away after switching to another branch. Now I have to do the clean for every branch switch to make sure my work dir is clean,

Answer (score 0):

The committed folders might have some files that would be added in your .gitignore so git isn't actually tracking those. This might be the reason that git is showing that in your switched branch since those are untracked and aren't added in the current branch's gitignore. This might be the issue, not sure.